# Performance testing audio jmeter

Tags: performance, post, audio, jmeter

I'm using JMeter to test the performance of a system that takes in audio files. I use HTTP Request to make the POST and handle sending the file. About 40% of the time, the system cannot understand the audio file being sent while other times it works fine. Does JMeter have some intricacy I am not accounting for?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is quite straightforward so the problem is somewhere else. Personally I would take the next steps:

- Enable saving of response body in case of error. It can be done by adding next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

  ```
  jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
  jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
  ```

  JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.
- Check logs on:

  - JMeter side - *jmeter.log* file, usually under JMeter's "bin" folder
  - Your application under test side

The possible reasons could be:

1. Your system is overloaded hence cannot properly process that many files.
2. You send incorrect [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) or file path is wrong, file doesn't exist
3. JMeter system is overloaded. Sending a file is quite "heavy" operation and JMeter default settings are not very suitable for high loads. Check [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for a collection of JMeter tweaks in order to get the maximum performance from your JMeter instance.